# Нужно найти непрерывные участки, где сумма элементов равна 0

Tags: java, алгоритм, eclipse, netbeans

Я написал начало кода, есть размер массива (300), а диапазон массива `[-100, ..., 100)`
ниже прикрепил начало кода. Помогите пожалуйста написать остальную часть, так как я пока что новичок в этом и не совсем разбираюсь.

```
public class Task3_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mass [] = new int[300];
        for (int i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
            mass[i] = ((int)(Math.random()*200) - 100);
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for(int x : mass) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пройти по массиву, посчитать сумму с накоплением. В полученном массиве искать дубликаты - сумма элементов между дубликатами нулевая.

Comment: А как в массиве искать дубликаты?

Comment: o_O Отсортировать, и в один проход искать идущие последовательно равные значения.

Comment: Как считается длина участка, например, для случая `[0, 0, 10, -5, 5, -10]`?

Comment: Может ему надо найти все подходящие условию участки? То есть из этого примера будут [0,1],[0,5],[1,5],[2,5],[3,4], ну и возможно единичные нули тоже надо учитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Простейший способ -- полным перебором вычислить суммы для каждой подпоследовательности во входном массиве, вывести те, сумма которых равна 0 (или другому заданному значению), увеличить счётчик:

```java
static int countSubarrays(int sum, int ... arr) {
    int count = 0;
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int subTotal = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            subTotal += arr[j];
            if (subTotal == sum) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(subArr(i, j, arr));
            }
        }
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

Метод `subArr` возвращает подпоследовательность между двумя индексами в виде строки для печати:

```java
static String subArr(int from, int to, int ... arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append('[').append(from).append("; ").append(to).append("]:");
    for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        sb.append("  ").append(arr[i]);
    }
    
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Тест: для диапазона значений `[-15; 15]`, 30 чисел:

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
int[] arr = random.ints(30, -15, 16).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) + "\n----");

System.out.println("Found " + countSubarrays(0, arr));
```

Результат:

```
[-3, 15, -11, 13, 8, -13, 5, 8, 13, 1, -2, -11, 9, 15, -6, 13, 4, -8, 13, 12, -12, 1, -8, 15, -7, -13, -10, -11, 9, 3]
----
[4; 6]:  8  -13  5
[5; 7]:  -13  5  8
[15; 26]:  13  4  -8  13  12  -12  1  -8  15  -7  -13  -10
[19; 20]:  12  -12
[22; 24]:  -8  15  -7
Found 5
```

Comment: Ну... для размера 300 за обозримое время ещё должно, наверное, работать

Comment: Ну можно было бы сделать массив накопительных сумм от 0 до N, но всё равно для получения сумм всех возможных подподследовательностей придется вычитать каждый элемент из каждой подсуммы, так что всё равно получится O(N^2) и понадобится дополнительный массив, то есть ещё и по памяти O(N).

Comment: Да, подмассивов в худшем случае квадратичное число.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FindInArr {

    private static final int[] testArr = {1,2,3,-6,3,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printZeroSumParts(testArr);
    }

    public static int arraySum(int[] arr) {
        if (arr == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : arr) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int[] getSubArray(int[] arr, int firstIndex, int lastIndex) {
        if (arr == null || lastIndex < firstIndex || firstIndex < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        int[] destArr = new int[lastIndex - firstIndex];
        System.arraycopy(arr, firstIndex, destArr, 0, lastIndex - firstIndex);
        return destArr;
    }

    public static void printZeroSumParts(int[] arr) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (arr.length == 1) {
            if (arr[0] == 0) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            }
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length - 1; j++) {
                int[] candidate = getSubArray(arr, i, j);
                if (arraySum(candidate) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(candidate));
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм предложил [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) в комментариях к ответу - сортировка накопительных сумм, печать отрезков для равных накопительных сумм.

Сложность *N·logN + K*, где *K* - объём печати. Если печатать подсписки то *K ≤ N<sup>3</sup>* (так сделано сейчас). Если печатать только диапазоны индексов, то *K ≤ N<sup>2</sup>*. Можно поменять формат печати так что окажется *K ≤ N* а все диапазоны будут напечатаны. Если требуется только сосчитать количество диапазонов, то *K ≤ N* (общая сложность *N·logN*).

Вместо сортировки одинаковые накопительные суммы можно накапливать в `HashMap`. Сложность будет *N + K*.

Код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Task3_1 {
    private static class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
        public final int index;
        public final long value;
        public Item(int index, long value) {
            this.index = index;
            this.value = value;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Item other) {
            return Long.compare(value, other.value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        // make random array
        final int max = 20;
        int array[] = new int[40];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            array[i] = ((int)(Math.random() * 2 * max) - max);
        }

        // print array
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // accumulate sums
        Item sums[] = new Item[array.length + 1];
        sums[0] = new Item(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            sums[i + 1] = new Item(i + 1, sums[i].value + array[i]);
        }

        // sort to group equal sums
        Arrays.sort(sums);

        // print all pairs of equal sums
        for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; ++i) {
            for (
                int j = i + 1;
                j < sums.length && sums[i].value == sums[j].value;
                ++j
            ) {
                System.out.print(
                    "[" + sums[i].index + ", " + sums[j].index + "):"
                );
                for (int k = sums[i].index; k < sums[j].index; ++k) {
                    System.out.print(" " + array[k]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Тесты:

> ```
> $ javac Task3_1.java
>
> $ java Task3_1
>  12 -16 -11 -7 0 -6 -5 14 -5 16 -6 -19 14 12 -7 -9 19 -4 -13 -18 -9 4 -8 -5 7 -3 19 -8 8 5 -6 -14 -11 9 -5 13 -3 18 19 11
> [27, 29): -8 8
> [7, 12): 14 -5 16 -6 -19
> [6, 38): -5 14 -5 16 -6 -19 14 12 -7 -9 19 -4 -13 -18 -9 4 -8 -5 7 -3 19 -8 8 5 -6 -14 -11 9 -5 13 -3 18
> [4, 5): 0
> [8, 13): -5 16 -6 -19 14
> [11, 15): -19 14 12 -7
> [10, 18): -6 -19 14 12 -7 -9 19 -4
> [2, 17): -11 -7 0 -6 -5 14 -5 16 -6 -19 14 12 -7 -9 19
>
> $ java Task3_1
>  -3 16 8 1 19 6 9 19 5 -5 -5 -18 10 9 1 -7 10 -2 2 14 7 -18 -1 -18 3 8 -7 9 -2 12 0 -20 -2 18 -20 0 -15 -6 3 -11
> [35, 36): 0
> [13, 25): 9 1 -7 10 -2 2 14 7 -18 -1 -18 3
> [13, 32): 9 1 -7 10 -2 2 14 7 -18 -1 -18 3 8 -7 9 -2 12 0 -20
> [25, 32): 8 -7 9 -2 12 0 -20
> [11, 26): -18 10 9 1 -7 10 -2 2 14 7 -18 -1 -18 3 8
> [11, 29): -18 10 9 1 -7 10 -2 2 14 7 -18 -1 -18 3 8 -7 9 -2
> [26, 29): -7 9 -2
> [15, 28): -7 10 -2 2 14 7 -18 -1 -18 3 8 -7 9
> [8, 10): 5 -5
> [8, 17): 5 -5 -5 -18 10 9 1 -7 10
> [8, 19): 5 -5 -5 -18 10 9 1 -7 10 -2 2
> [10, 17): -5 -18 10 9 1 -7 10
> [10, 19): -5 -18 10 9 1 -7 10 -2 2
> [17, 19): -2 2
> [22, 34): -1 -18 3 8 -7 9 -2 12 0 -20 -2 18
> [30, 31): 0
> ```